# Errors when viewing PHP file in browser, okay when executed in Terminal

Tags: php, authentication, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have been able to create a PHP file locally that utilises the Google Analytics Data API to call back some metrics on my ecommerce store. I am able to see the script results within Terminal, however when trying to view the same file in a browser it returns errors regarding authentication.

I've followed the steps here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries and have run the `$ composer require google/analytics-data` command in the /Users/a/ folder.

My PHP file is located in /Users/a/Documents/project/sample.php and is returning authentication errors like:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: { "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT", "domain": "googleapis.com", "errorInfoMetadata": { "method": "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport", "service": "analyticsdata.googleapis.com" }, "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "code": 7, "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "method": "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport", "service": "analyticsdata.googleapis.com" } } ] } thrown in /Users/a/Documents/behaveia/vendor/google/gax/src/ApiException.php on line 267
```

Should the GCloud SDK and PHP setup have been run in the same folder?
*FYI - I haven't had to setup a local dev environment before*

Comment: Any thoughts @cbroe? You had some good ideas on my other post.